# Printed dipole vs ordinary (3D) dipole

Tags: rf, antenna, microwave, pcb-antenna, dipole

In order to make a comparison between an ordinary (3D) half - wavelength dipole and its printed (planar version), I've done a simulation in both cases. Both were designed to work at 3GHz (100mm wavelength). Input port is a voltage source with 75Ohm of impedance. To avoid dielectric effects, I've not considered any dielectric substrate for the printed dipole.

1. The 3D dipole has been built with:

- Length 45mm (a bit lower than half-wavelength. That's a choice the result of the simulator optimization).
- Radius 1mm (much lower than the Length)
- Gap1  1mm (much lower than the Length)

[image]

The results are:

**S11 (reflection coefficient). It's minimum at 3GHz. So it's fine.**

[image]

**Radiation pattern cuts (at 3GHz)**

[image]

2. The printed dipole has the same size values (Length 45mm, Width 1mm, Gap 1mm) of the 3D one, except for the fact it's a strip.

[image]

The results are:

**S11 (reflection coefficient).**

[image]

**Radiation pattern cuts (at 3GHz).**

[image]

---

**In conclusion**:

- same resonance frequency (for a fixed length)
- same matching at the resonance frequence
- same pattern shape and same directivity values

(Only very very very small differences are present in the previous graphs)

but a printed dipole has lots of advantages, being lightweight, easily embeddable with active devices in PCB, and flexible to make flexible pcb.

**I can't believe there isn't at least one disadvantage in choosing the printed version.** I would have expected a big variation in radiation pattern, since the 3d dipole has the same shape if seen from each direction on the transverse plane, while a printed dipole is a strip if observed frontally, and a wire if observed laterally. But the simulations say I'm wrong: the printed dipole is as omnidirectional (and with same directivity value) as the 3D dipole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diameter and cross-section of the dipole element do have some effect on bandwidth (the thicker the element, the broader the bandwidth) but very little effect on directivity. This is because the cross-sectional dimensions (1 mm) are still small compared to a wavelength at 3 GHz (100 mm).

However, the printed version isn't going to be floating in space, but supported by a PCB dielectric, which will have a significant effect. The dipole length for resonance will be shorter, depending on the dielectric constant of the material, and there will be some decrease in efficiency as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain me why (intuitively) the thicker the element, the broader the bandwidth?